# How can I extract a datetime pattern from any string in Java?

Tags: java, jodatime

How can I extract a datetime pattern from any string in Java?

The pattern is `"YYYYMMddkm"`.

Are there any Joda time helper methods for this?

`String 1: 2014041507393_somefile.somemore`

`String 2: _somefile2014041507393.somemore`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following regular expression:

```
^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$
```

as in

```
String date = "2014041507393_somefile.somemore";

if (str.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: javadoc says: Returns: true if, and only if, this string matches the given regular expression. Doesn't it mean that the WHOLE string needs to match the regex?

Comment: As we are using a REGEX and not a single String, "string matches the given regular expression" means that the string matches with any of possible combination from regular expression

Answer (score 0):

You will have to get rid of letters yourself. I don't think Joda time will have any methods to do this for you.

Answer (score 0):

First use regular expression and then parse string in Java for use later:

```
if (str.matches("\\d{4}-\\d{2}-\\d{2}")) {
     Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH).parse(str);
    System.out.println(date); // Example: Sat May 14 00:00:00 BOT 2014
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `parse` method of `SimpleDateFormat`:

```
SimpleDateFormat format = SimpleDateFormat("YYYYMMddkm");
format.parse(string, pos);
```